# How can I get a "shareable ID" of a picture using the DriveApp in Google script to insert it in a Google sheet cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to insert a picture located on my Drive in a cell on a spreadsheet. To do so, I need the shareable ID of the picture file. The shareable ID can be obtained by manually clicking on the file and click "Get shareable link".

This is the link to the example image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qoWmf1eks6BZiMNv1PByvr6lcPLT0png

with the ID being : 1qoWmf1eks6BZiMNv1PByvr6lcPLT0png

When I try to execute my google script and use file.getId(), I obtain another ID. The image does not appear in the google sheet cell when using that the ID obtained with my script. The image appear only with the ID from the shareable link obtained manually. Does someone know how to solve this?

Thank you

See the script to obtain the file ID below:

```js
function getFileID() {
  var name = "m285741_200316_001_FOV_enhanced.png";
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(name);

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
   file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
   var URL = file.getUrl();
   var ID = file.getId();
    
 }
  return ID;
 
}
```

Comment: What is the ID you are obtaining with the `.getId()` function? Do you have only one file called `"m285741_200316_001_FOV_enhanced.png"` in your Google Drive?

Comment: I have only one file with this name. I now get the same ID with .getId() than the one I get manually. However, when I use the formula =getFileID(filename) in a sheet cell, I get an error message: #ERROR! Exception: You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFilesByName. Required permissions (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readOnly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to run custom functions that require special authorization.

As you can read in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced):

> If your custom function throws the error message You do not have permission to call X service., the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function.
>
> To use a service other than those listed above, create a custom menu that runs an Apps Script function instead of writing a custom function. A function that is triggered from a menu will ask the user for authorization if necessary and can consequently use all Apps Script services.

Consider using the suggested workaround. [Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus) a guide on using custom menus.